# Performance benefit of replacing multiple bools with one int and using bit masking?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a C++ application where I use multiple bools through, to check conditions for IF statements. Using cachegrind my branch misprediction is about 4%, so not too bad. However, I do need to try and increase the performance.

Would it be worthwhile to replace 12x bools with a single int. I am on 64-bit Red Hat and I believe bools are represented using 4-byte ints. Therefore I am using 48 bytes, rather than 12 bits.

If I was to use bit masking I think I would still need to store bit patterns for accessing specific bits in the overall int. Would the need to store these bit patterns offset the bytes saves from reducing number of pools and therefore make this idea pointless?

Comment: You're not going to know until you try and then profile it, guessing at this stage is counter-productive

Comment: It depends on the total context.  If there are only 12 booleans, then they will fit in a single cache line, and it's probable that the added bit masking will slow things down.  If you have large arrays or vectors of a `struct` with 12 bools, on the other hand, putting them in a single `int` will improve locality, and _might_ speed things up (but you won't know until you try it).

Comment: 12x bools would fix in a cache line, so I would guess the cache misses are not a main bottleneck. But if your code may expand to support more (and more) bools, it's worth to try bit masking, like c++'s specialized std::vector<bool>.

Comment: Other questions to ask are:  Is it worth your effort? Is it worth making the code less readable? 
If I get your destcription correctly, my rough guess is this is not worth optimization, unless your bool-s are inside a class which will have thousands of instances or you are using the bool-s inside the deepest cycle which determines your execution time critically.
The c++ way is to encapsulate and optimize the implementanion latter.
But yes, you can gain here by keeping the whole thing in one proceessor register and bitmasking by constants on machine instruction level.

Comment: @EdChum I completely disagree. I am asking for a theoretical basis on whether it is worthwhile to make a labour-intensive change. If somebody says "this is unlikely to help" its better to have that knowledge than to spend a few hours and then realise.

Comment: @user997112 It's unlikely to help doesn't mean that it won't help.  If you need to improve performance, then the only way to know whether this change will improve performance or not is to try it.  It may help; it may not.

Answer (score 2):

Although the only way to find out for sure is to try it out, there are several considerations that may influence your decision.

First, the amount of storage would go down: you would not have to "store bit patterns for accessing specific bits in the overall `int`", because these patterns would become constants inside your program "baked into" the binary code.

Second, you should look at the use pattern of your flags. If you often check combinations of several flags, you may be able to replace some of these checks with a single masking operation.

Third, you should consider the aspect of writing the data back: with separate `bool` values each write goes to its own location, while a solution with flags would be writing to the same byte or two each time that you need to modify your flags. On the other hand, modifying several flags at once can be done in a single write.

Finally, you should consider the question of readability: your program is bound to become more complex after this change. The the gains in performance may be too small in comparison to losses of readability, because the code will run faster when the hardware become faster in a few years, but less readable code would remain less readable forever.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to know for sure is profiling. Using ints may even be slower on some architectures since accessing single bits may involve some bit shifting and masking.